# tomcat not opening in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Please help, I am new to Eclipse and I got the following error in my eclipse IDE (Previously  I was using NetBeans)
Whenever I start my Tomcat server for running the project I get the Following error

**I copied and pasted the console output**

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid
>   byte tag in constant pool: 15     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1917)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1806)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1765)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1751)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1255)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)

Answer (score 1):

if you have deployed a web project to tomcat and then this error showed up then add `metadata-complete="true"` to your web.xml.

If tomcat is not able to start bare bone, then check if you are in Java level 8 in preferences. Shift back to Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You may add some information..

How did you start the tomcat server: with a plugin, with right-click on the web project and run as, or by starting it from the servers view?

If you double click on tomcat in server view, you'll see the settings page. There is a link under "general information", like 3rd line, which says "Runtime Environment". Click it and check whether you chose the right installation path and JRE (I prefer using my JDK).

Which Java version do you use, and which tomcat version?